# concatenate column names with non-zero column values in r

Tags: r

I have a data set with name, score 1, score 2, score 3, score 4, score 5, score 6 columns. I want to create a new column "rule" by concatenating column names and non-zero column values.

```
name    score1  score2  score3  score4  score5  score6  rule
name1   0       0       0       0       0       0        NA
name2   0       1       0       0       0       0        score2:1
name3   0       1       1       0       1       0        score2:1,score3:1,score5:1
name4   1       1       1       1       1       1        score1:1,score2:1,score3:1,score4:1,score5:1,score6:1
```

I wrote the following code for the concatenation but I am not able to exclude column names with zero values.

```
cols <- colnames(data)[-1]
data <- data[, rules := do.call(paste, c(lapply(cols, function(x) paste(x, get(x), sep=":")),              
                                          sep=","))]
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Can you provide your data in an easier format? I suggest `dput(data)`. Otherwise, it's difficult to just scrape it when there are spaces in a column.

Comment: @r2evans can you please try again? i have removed the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using data.table, but I don't know a method using that to do this by reference. I'm not sure if your data is so large that you need it to be done by reference or not based on your question.

Here's a fairly clear tidy way to do this:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
name    score1 score2 score3 score4 score5 score6
name1   0       0       0       0       0       0
name2   0       1       0       0       0       0
name3   0       1       1       0       1       0
name4   1       1       1       1       1       1",
header = TRUE,
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

rule <- df %>%
  # gather data to long format with one row for each column/value pair
  gather(key = "colname",value = "value",score1:score6) %>%
  # remove zeroes for rule generation
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  # For each single value join the name and quantity
  mutate(value = paste(colname,value,sep = ": ")) %>%
  # For each name pull things together
  group_by(name) %>%
  # Collapse the results for that name into a single character vector
  summarise(value = paste(value,collapse = ", "))

# Join the rules back to the dataframe
df <- df %>%
  left_join(rule)
```

Result:

```
> df
   name score1 score2 score3 score4 score5 score6
1 name1      0      0      0      0      0      0
2 name2      0      1      0      0      0      0
3 name3      0      1      1      0      1      0
4 name4      1      1      1      1      1      1
                                                             value
1                                                             <NA>
2                                                        score2: 1
3                                  score2: 1, score3: 1, score5: 1
4 score1: 1, score2: 1, score3: 1, score4: 1, score5: 1, score6: 1
```